# Why does order of comparison matter for this apply/lambda inequality?

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry, it's not a great title.  Simple example though:

(pandas version 0.16.1)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x':range(1,5), 'y':[1,1,1,9] })
```

Works fine:

```
df.apply( lambda x: x > x.mean() )

       x      y
0  False  False
1  False  False
2   True  False
3   True   True
```

Shouldn't this work the same?

```
df.apply( lambda x: x.mean() < x )
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-467-6f32d50055ea> in <module>()
----> 1 df.apply( lambda x: x.mean() < x )

C:\Users\ei\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   3707                     if reduce is None:
   3708                         reduce = True
-> 3709                     return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
   3710             else:
   3711                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

C:\Users\ei\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   3797             try:
   3798                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 3799                     results[i] = func(v)
   3800                     keys.append(v.name)
   3801             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-467-6f32d50055ea> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df.apply( lambda x: x.mean() < x )

C:\Users\ei\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in wrapper(self, other, axis)
    586             return NotImplemented
    587         elif isinstance(other, (np.ndarray, pd.Index)):
--> 588             if len(self) != len(other):
    589                 raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
    590             return self._constructor(na_op(self.values, np.asarray(other)),

TypeError: ('len() of unsized object', u'occurred at index x')
```

For a counter-example, these both work:

```
df.mean() < df

df > df.mean()
```

Comment: Try adding brackets, because Python might be parsing it as `( (lambda x: x.mean()) < x )` instead of `( lambda x: (x.mean() < x) )`

Comment: That doesn't work for me either.  Did it work for you?  I did play around with parentheses a little but nothing I tried worked and I couldn't really tell how they would change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Finally found the bug for this - [Issue 9369](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9369)

As indicated in the issue -

> left = 0 > s works (e.g. a python scalar). So I think this is being
>   treated as a 0-dim array (its a np.int64) (and not as a scalar when
>   called.) I'll mark as a bug. Feel free to dig in

The issue occurs when using comparison operators with a `numpy` datatype (like np.int64 or np.float64, etc) on the left side of the comparison operator . A simple fix for this maybe as @santon noted in his answer, to convert the number to python scalar, rather than using `numpy` scalar.

---

**Old :**

I tried in Pandas 0.16.2.

I did the following on your original df -

```
In [22]: df['z'] = df['x'].mean() < df['x']

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   x  y      z
0  1  1  False
1  2  1  False
2  3  1   True
3  4  9   True

In [27]: df['z'].mean() < df['z']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-afc8a7b869b4> in <module>()
----> 1 df['z'].mean() < df['z']

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
    586             return NotImplemented
    587         elif isinstance(other, (np.ndarray, pd.Index)):
--> 588             if len(self) != len(other):
    589                 raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
    590             return self._constructor(na_op(self.values, np.asarray(other)),

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Seems like a bug to me, I can compare boolean means with int and vice versa fine, but only issue comes when using boolean mean with boolean (though I do not think it makes sense to take mean() for boolean) -

```
In [24]: df['z'] < df['x']
Out[24]:
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool

In [25]: df['z'] < df['x'].mean()
Out[25]:
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
Name: z, dtype: bool

In [26]: df['x'].mean() < df['z']
Out[26]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: z, dtype: bool
```

---

I tried and reproduced the issue in Pandas 0.16.1 , it can also be reproduced using -

```
In [10]: df['x'].mean() < df['x']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-4e5dab1545af> in <module>()
----> 1 df['x'].mean() < df['x']

/opt/anaconda/envs/np18py27-1.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.pyc in wrapper(self, other, axis)
    586             return NotImplemented
    587         elif isinstance(other, (np.ndarray, pd.Index)):
--> 588             if len(self) != len(other):
    589                 raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
    590             return self._constructor(na_op(self.values, np.asarray(other)),

TypeError: len() of unsized object

In [11]: df['x'] < df['x'].mean()
Out[11]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: x, dtype: bool
```

Seems like this is also a bug  which has been fixed in Pandas version 0.16.2 (except for when mixing booleans with integer). I would suggest upgrade your pandas version using -

```
pip install pandas --upgrade
```

---

Comment: You don't have to guess what I did, I posted 100% of the code I used.  Does my exact code (as posted) work OK for you?  (I'm in pandas 0.16.1 as noted above)

Comment: You posted you did - `df.apply( lambda x: x > x.mean() )` , that is not reassigning the return to `df` .

Comment: Without the reassignment, it is working fine , `df.apply( lambda x: x.mean() < x )` does not give me any error

Comment: My pandas version is `'0.16.2'` .

Comment: I tried in pandas 0.16.1 , I was able to reproduce it, seems like a bug which is fixed in 0.16.2

Comment: Great, thanks, I'll try and find the issue on github and update the answer.

Comment: @JohnE Finally found the bug for this - https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9369

Comment: As best I can understand the github thread, this isn't a 0.16.1 vs 0.16.2 thing, but that definitely does seem to concern the same issue so I'll check this off as the answer.  Thanks for tracking it down, I was not having any luck.

Answer (score 2):

I think it has to do with how the greater-than operator is overloaded. When using an overloaded function, if the data types are different on the left or right, the order matters. (Python has a complicated way of figuring out which overloaded function to use.) You can get your code to work by casting the result of `mean()` (which is `numpy.float64`) to a simple float:

```
df.apply( lambda x: float(x.mean()) < x )
```

For some reason it seems like the pandas code is treating the `numpy.float64` like an array, which might be why it fails.